# Unable to open FFmpegFrameRecorder stream on a UDP port on Windows

Tags: java, ffmpeg, udp, javacv

I am trying to stream a webcam video with FFmpegFrameRecorder and play it with "ffplay" command, but the ffplay command fails with the following message 'udp://127.0.0.1:25777: Invalid data found when processing input/0'.

The code I am using for streaming the video,

```
 public void startStreaming() throws Exception {
    OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
    grabber.setVideoCodec(27);
    grabber.setImageMode(FrameGrabber.ImageMode.COLOR);
    grabber.setBitsPerPixel(10);
    grabber.setFormat("yuvj420p");
    grabber.start();
    FFmpegFrameRecorder  recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("udp://127.0.0.1:25777", grabber.getImageWidth(), grabber.getImageHeight());
    recorder.setFrameRate(grabber.getFrameRate());
    recorder.setVideoBitrate(grabber.getVideoBitrate());
    recorder.setOption("listen", "1");
    recorder.setFormat("h264");
    recorder.setPixelFormat(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
    recorder.setVideoCodecName("h264_videotoolbox");
    recorder.setVideoCodec(27);
    recorder.setOption("keyint", "10");
    recorder.start();}
```

And I am calling the recorder.record in a thread as follows,

```
frame = grabber.grabFrame();                      
recorder.record(frame);
```

After starting the stream, I opened the command line and tried to play the stream with the following command,

```
ffplay udp://127.0.0.1:25777
```

And it is failing with the following message,

```
udp://127.0.0.1:25777: Invalid data found when processing input/0
```

To get the stream information, I used the following command,

```
ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:25777
```

And it showed the following output,

```
[h264 @ 0000014dd1424880] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000014dd1424880] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000014dd1424880] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000014dd1424880] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000014dd1424880] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000014dd1424880] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000014dd1424880] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000014dd1424880] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000014dd1424880] no frame!
```

But when I tried with TCP protocol it is working fine and I am able to play the video.
How can I fix this issue? this is the first time I am using the FFmpeg and JavaCV.

Comment: UDP is an unreliable protocol, so we need to use a format that can deal with lost packets.

Comment: As far as I know `h264_videotoolbox` is supported only be Apple's hardware, but if it's working with TCP it should also work with UDP. Try: Start FFplay before starting the UDP transmission. (there is no reliability issues with localhost 127.0.0.1, but the UDP keeps transmitting even if no one is listening. When you start FFplay [after] it receives bytes at the middle of a stream and shows error messages). The messages are supposed to end when FFplay gets synchronized with the stream.

Comment: Thank you @Rotem, "Start FFplay before starting the UDP transmission" this one solved my issue.